# Crystal Reports - How do I reset the page count for each group?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

How do I reset the page count per group in my report?

Each group contains about 5-7 pages worth of data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way of resetting the page number on change of group is to check the "Reset Page Number After" option in the section expert for the group footer, in the Crystal Reports Designer.

Answer (score 2):

1st Formula:  HeaderReset - This formula should be placed in the page header of the report.  It will reset the counter when the report is processed to the next page.  Counter is a variable that stores the number as the report processes each record.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar counter:=0
```

2nd Formula: CountDetails - This formula should be placed in the Details section.  It will count each record and increment by one.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar counter;
counter:=counter+1
```

You will now need to use the CountDetails formula to force the new page based on the necessary number of records.   To do this:
bullet

Go to Format/Section and select the Details section.
bullet

Click on the X+2 button to the right of the "New Page After" option.  Be sure not to place a check in the New Page After box.  Once you click on the button, you will be placed in the formula editor.  Enter the following formula:

> {@CountDetails}=7   (enter the number of records you need on each
>   page) bullet

This condition will force a new page when Crystal reaches the seventh record in the details section.  The count will reset to zero at the beginning of each page due to the @HeaderReset formula.

If you need to count the Group Header records instead of the Details section, follow the above instructions for the details section, but place the formula and condition in the Group Header section instead of the Details section.

To hide the formula fields in the header and details section, right click on the field and go to format font.  Change the color to white and you will not be able to see them.

Comment: To hide a formula field, I recommend going into its properties and turning on the "suppress" property.  If you just change the font color, the user can still see it by selecting the entire page.